# Компиляция модулей в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Что станет с модулями на python, если скомпировать код, например через py_compiler? Будут ли они сохранены в коде программы. Например, если код будет построен с использованием 'Colorama', будет ли изменение цвета консоли и в итоговой версии программы?

```py
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
print(Fore.RED + 'Hello world')
```

Comment: Ничего не станет. Не будут сохранены, будут также загружаться из других файлов. И кстати, все скрипты при первом запуске неявно компилируются.

Comment: Что такое `py_compiler`? Такого модуля нет ни в стандартной библиотеке, ни в `PyPI`. Может, Вы имели в виду `py_compile`?